# Trying to decript in java the oracle procedure DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.DESDECRYPT

Tags: java, oracle, encryption

I'm trying to adapt this code to java in order to reduce the number of calls to DB:

```
--set serveroutput on
declare
  l_aux        NUMBER;
  l_cle        RAW(9) := utl_raw.cast_to_raw('example21');
  l_crypt_raw  VARCHAR2(200);
  l_crypt_str  VARCHAR2(200);  
  p_txt_desencrip varchar2(200):='8387F8937F5F842F805C44B88429D2CD';
BEGIN
  l_crypt_raw := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2( p_txt_desencrip));

  DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.DESDECRYPT ( input          =>  p_txt_desencrip
                                           , key            =>  l_cle
                                           , decrypted_data =>  l_crypt_raw 
                                           );

  l_crypt_str := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(l_crypt_raw);

  l_aux := LENGTH(l_crypt_str);

  l_crypt_str := RPAD(l_crypt_str,l_aux-ASCII(SUBSTR(l_crypt_str,l_aux)));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Decypted message->' ||  l_crypt_str); 

END;
```

I have been seen all attepts of solving this task, but anyway my main problem is that my key have 9 characters. Here is my java code:

```
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
 
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream;
import com.sun.mail.util.BASE64EncoderStream;
 
public class Test{
 
    private static Cipher ecipher;
    private static Cipher dcipher;
 
    private static SecretKey key;
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        try {
            String clave =  "example21";
            // generate secret key using DES algorithm
            SecretKey key2 = new SecretKeySpec(clave.getBytes(), 0, 9, "DES");

            ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
             
            // initialize the ciphers with the given key
             
            ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key2);
                     
            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key2);
                     
            String encrypted = encrypt("text to encrypt");
            System.out.println(encrypted);
            String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted);
            System.out.println("Decrypted: " + decrypted);
        }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.out.println("No Such Algorithm:" + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            System.out.println("No Such Padding:" + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Key:" + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
    }
 
    public static String encrypt(String str) {
 
        try {
            // encode the string into a sequence of bytes using the named charset
            // storing the result into a new byte array. 
            byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");
            byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);
            // encode to base64
            enc = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(enc);
            return new String(enc);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
 
    public static String decrypt(String str) {
 
        try {
            // decode with base64 to get bytes
            byte[] dec = BASE64DecoderStream.decode(str.getBytes());
            byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);
            // create new string based on the specified charset
            return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
 
}
```

I've tried differents ways and algorithms but I allways get the error "Invalid Key:Wrong key size"...

Any have a suggestion of what I should try?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Firstly,** the `DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT` is deprecated and should not be used.
- **Secondly**, `DES` was broken more than 20 years ago and should not be used anymore.

As for your question. The documentation for
`DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.DESDECRYPT` have the following to say about the key parameter:

> If the key length is missing or is less than 8 bytes, then the
> procedure raises the error ORA-28234 "Key length too short." Note that
> if larger keys are used, extra bytes are ignored. **So a 9-byte key will
> not generate an exception.**

So **Java** just validates the key a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm just decrypting what was encrypted (not by me). My PLSQL code actually works with that key, just want to know how to do it in Java

Comment: Read the quote. The PLSQL code ignores any bytes in excess of 8 bytes. So the last byte in the key is not in use. You get the error because Java don't ignore extra bytes in the key.